# Hardware specifications for WOL (Wake On Lan)

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter, hardware-rec, wake-on-lan

I am planning to buy a computer, which I would like to start using [Wake-On-Lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) from outside the LAN. I was looking on the internet and there is lot of information to be confused.

1) What are the considerations when procuring Network Card and the Mother Board?

2) Do I need to keep the computer in suspend mode or can it be shutdown completely?

Comment: WOL packets will not traverse the internet (outside of your LAN). Also, afaik WOL will only power on a machine, so it can't resume a suspended machine.

Comment: WOL works outside LAN also with port forwarding set in the router. And there are lot of tools (web and other way) to send the magic packet.

Answer (score 0):

Manufactures will include it in the specifications if it supports WOL (My ASUS motherboard supports it, can't remember the model of the top of my head).

And also the computer can be completely shut down, and still WOL (as long as power is connected Lol).

And also, you are right about using WOL through a NAT, as I have successfully done this before